# How can I let people login into my website with their yahoo or facebook or twitter account?

Tags: php

I tried a lot, but wasn't able to add openid in my website using Yahoo, Twitter, and Facebook. I have added Google as open id in my website but I am not able to add Facebook, Twitter, and Yahoo.

So how can I let people log in into my website with their Yahoo or Facebook or Twitter accounts?

Comment: Try the links at the right. -->

Answer (score 2):

Along wih Teez's answer the basic process is generally

1. Register with the specific site for use of their api / building app
2. Setup settings with the site (callback url, etc) and get a secret and public key
3. From your site send the user to a authorization page on the specific site
4. after they "authorize" your app/site your callback url will be called with information from the specific site. Usually will include a long term key/code that you have to save in a database for use with api calls to the specific site
5. Use the api calls with the long term key/code from earlier to retrieve the users information and save it.
6. Any time you need the user to "login" use the specific sites api call to make sure the long term key/code is still valid if not make them reauthorize to get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use APIs of the services (Google, Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo) or may be OpenID  that as well.

Not possible to post code here but links below will help you lot:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth

http://openid.net/add-openid/

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

http://wilkinsonlab.ca/home/node/31